# Image size is taken as (0,0) even though it's not

Tags: ios, swift, filter, gpuimage

I'm using `GPUImage` with `Swift 3.0` and am trying to add an image filter, however the `GPUImage` crashes. Crash log: image size should be more than 0.

**My code:**

```
let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)
var image = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)

if image.size.height > 0 && image.size.width > 0 {
    let contrastfilter = GPUImageContrastFilter()
    image = contrastfilter.image(byFilteringImage: image)
}
```

**Error:**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
reason: 'Passed image must not be empty - it should be at least 1px tall and wide'
```

**Side note:**

I've already checked whether the height is greater than zero and called the function, however an error is returned.

Comment: Make sure image object not nil check here https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1362

Comment: @karthikeyan `image` is not `nil`

Comment: Getting this error as well.

Comment: I couldn't get any solution. :( , I will update you tomorrow with the work around I had used.